# JS + CANVAS Projectile Motion

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, canvas, physics

Basically you've got a canvas, and you can click it to launch a ball in a certain angle and speed, everything is working fine, except for the arrow tip of the vector thing. I can't get it to draw correctly. Sometimes it can't detect collisions. It seems to happen when the ball has a really high speed.

I managed to solve the collisions problem, but sometimes the colors of the balls change, that shouldn't be a thing.

How should I approach the arrow tip thing? I mean, how can I draw it at the correct position and angle (so basically the TRANSLATE and ROTATE functions).

```js
class Ball{
    
    
    constructor(positionP, velocityP, accelerationP, radiusP, contextP, colorP){
        
        this.radius = radiusP;
        this.context = contextP;
        this.color = colorP; 
        

        this.colliding = false;
        this.collidingColor = "yellow";
        
        
        this.friction = 0.97;
        this.mass = 1;
        
        this.position = {
            x: positionP.x,
            y: positionP.y
        }
        
        this.velocity = {
            x: velocityP.x,
            y: velocityP.y
        }
        
        this.acceleration = {
            x : 0,
            y : accelerationP/60
        }
    }
    
    draw(){
        
        if(this.colliding) this.context.fillStyle = this.collidingColor;
        else this.context.fillStyle = this.color; 
            
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        this.context.fill();
    }
    
    move(){
               
        this.velocity.x += this.acceleration.x;
        this.velocity.y = this.velocity.y + this.acceleration.y;


        this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
        this.position.y -= this.velocity.y;
        
    }
}



//screen labels
let fpsInd = document.getElementById("fpsIndicator");
let mouseInd = document.getElementById("mouse");
let hypIndicator = document.getElementById("hypotenuse");
let oppIndicator = document.getElementById("opp");
let adjIndicator = document.getElementById("adj");
let thetaIndicator = document.getElementById("theta");


let manualLauncherBtn = document.getElementById("launchManual");
let manualVelocity = document.getElementById("mVelocity");
let manualAngle = document.getElementById("mAngle");

var strThetaChar = thetaIndicator.innerHTML.split(" ")[0];
var currentThetaRadians;

var CANVAS_CLICKED = false;
let canvas = document.getElementById("area");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var frames = 0;
var fps = 0;
var lastCallTime;

let Balls = [];

/////////////////////////motion variables//////////
let velocity_initial;
let angle;
let time;


//VERTICAL 
let y_velocity_original = 0;
let y_velocity_final = 0;
let y_original = 0;
let y_final = 0;
let y_acceleration = 0;
let max_height = 0;


//HORIZONTAL 
let x_velocity_original = 0;
let x_velocity_final = 0;
let x_original = 0;
let x_final = 0;
let x_acceleration = 0;




canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event)=>{
    updateMouse(event);
    solveTriangle();
});

canvas.addEventListener('click', () => {
   CANVAS_CLICKED = true;    
   MotionMain(ctx); 
});

manualLauncherBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   performManuaLaunch(); 
});

var origin = {
    x: 0,
    y: canvas.height
}

var originBalls = {
    x: 0,
    y: canvas.height-1
}

var mousePosition = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}




window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
function loop() {
      
  frames ++;
  getFPS();
    
  console.log(CANVAS_CLICKED);    
    
  if(frames % 3 == 0) 
    fpsInd.innerHTML = "FPS: "+fps;      

  clearScreen();    
  workNextFrame();    
    

  CANVAS_CLICKED = false;    
    
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);  
}

//motion functions
function MotionMain(ctx){      
        
    y_acceleration = parseFloat(y_acceleration);  
    solveProblem();
    showLaunchData();
    
    newBall();
}

function performManuaLaunch(){    
    let launchData = createManualBall();
    let {ball, velocities, maxHeight, s, t} = launchData;
           
    showManualData(velocities, t, maxHeight, s);  
    Balls.push(ball);
}

function showManualData(velocities, t, maxHeight, s){
    let a = document.getElementById("acceleration").value;
    
    document.getElementById('velocity').value = manualVelocity.value;
    document.getElementById('launchAngle').value = manualAngle.value;
    document.getElementById('Yvel').value = velocities.y.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('Xvel').value = velocities.x.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('time').value = parseFloat(t).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('mHeight').value = parseFloat(maxHeight).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('Xdisplacement').value = parseFloat(s).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('yAcceleration').value = a;
}

function createManualBall(){
    let mTime, mDisplacementX, mMaxHeight, mBall;
    
    let m_angle = parseFloat(manualAngle.value);
    let m_vel = parseFloat(manualVelocity.value);
    
    let velY = Math.sin( (m_angle * Math.PI) / 180) * m_vel;
    let velX = Math.cos( (m_angle * Math.PI) / 180) * m_vel;
    
        
    let accelerationY = parseFloat(document.getElementById("acceleration").value);
    
    // 1- get the time -> Vf=Vo+at --> t=Vo-Vf/a
    mTime = Math.abs( velY / accelerationY )*2;
    mTime = mTime.toFixed(3);
    
    // 2- get the range -> Xf=Vo*t
    mDisplacementX = (velX * mTime).toFixed(0);
    
    // 3- get the maximum height -> Vo*Vo/2*a
    mMaxHeight = Math.abs( (velY*velY) / ( 2 * accelerationY ) ).toFixed(2);
    
    mBall = new Ball(originBalls, {
        x: velX,
        y: velY
    }, accelerationY,10, ctx, "yellow");
    
    return {
        t: mTime,
        s: mDisplacementX,
        maxHeight: mMaxHeight,
        velocities: {x: velX, y: velY},
        ball: mBall
    }
}


function solveProblem(){
    
    time = 0;
    x_final = 0;
    max_height = 0;
        
    // 1- get the time -> Vf=Vo+at --> t=Vo-Vf/a
    time = Math.abs( (y_velocity_original - y_velocity_final) / y_acceleration )*2;
    time = time.toFixed(3);
    
    // 2- get the range -> Xf=Vo*t
    x_final = (x_velocity_original * time).toFixed(0);
    
    // 3- get the maximum height -> Vo*Vo/2*a
    max_height = Math.abs( (y_velocity_original*y_velocity_original) / (2*y_acceleration) ).toFixed(2);  
    
    //alert("time: "+time+"s range: "+x_final+"m Max.Height: "+max_height+"m");
}

function showLaunchData(){
    document.getElementById('velocity').value = velocity_initial;
    document.getElementById('launchAngle').value = angle;
    document.getElementById('Yvel').value = y_velocity_original;
    document.getElementById('Xvel').value = x_velocity_original;
    document.getElementById('time').value = time;
    document.getElementById('mHeight').value = max_height;
    document.getElementById('Xdisplacement').value = x_final;
    document.getElementById('yAcceleration').value = y_acceleration;
}

function newBall(){
    
    if(!CANVAS_CLICKED) return;
    
    let c;
    
    
    
    if(angle <= 30) c = "red";
    else if(angle <= 45 && angle > 30) c = "green";
    else if(angle <= 60 && angle > 45) c = "blue";
    else if(angle <= 90 && angle > 60) c = "black";
    
    
    //c = randomColor();
      
    var ball = new Ball( originBalls, {
        x: x_velocity_original,
        y: y_velocity_original
    }, y_acceleration, 8, ctx, c);
    
    
    Balls.unshift(ball);
}

function randomColor(){
    let colors = ['red','cyan','blue','Dark Blue','Light Blue','Purple','Lime','Magenta','silver','gray','green','orange','brown','maroon'];
    return colors[randomInteger(0,colors.length)];
}
function randomInteger(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////

function workNextFrame(){
    drawVectorTip(); 
    drawVectorLine(); 
    
    drawAngleIcon();
    drawAngleArc();
    
    
    updateBalls();
    cleanBalls();
    
    if(Balls.length > 1) checkCollisions();
}

function updateBalls(){
    for(let i = Balls.length-1 ; i >= 0; i--){       
        Balls[i].draw();
        Balls[i].move();
    }
}

function cleanBalls(){
    
    let BallsCopy = Balls;
        
    for(let i = Balls.length-1; i >= 0; i--){       
        let ball = Balls[i];
        if(ball.position.y > canvas.height){
            BallsCopy = Balls.filter( (ball) => {
                return ball.position.y <= canvas.height     
            });
        }        
    }
    
    Balls = BallsCopy;
    
    document.getElementById("ballCount").innerHTML = "NºBalls: "+Balls.length;
}

function drawVectorTip(){
    
    var img = document.getElementById("tip");
    
    ctx.save();
    
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(-currentThetaRadians);
    
    ctx.drawImage(img, mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y, 40, 40);
    
    ctx.restore();
}



function drawAngleArc(){
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(origin.x, origin.y, 30, 0, -currentThetaRadians, true);
    ctx.stroke(); 
    
    //document.getElementById("currentRads").innerHTML = currentThetaRadians.toFixed(3);
}

function solveTriangle(){
    var opp = Math.floor(canvas.height - mousePosition.y);
    var adj = Math.floor(mousePosition.x);
    var hyp = Math.floor(Math.sqrt( opp*opp + adj*adj ));
    
    var thetaRadians = Math.atan(opp/adj);
    var thetaDegrees = (thetaRadians*180)/Math.PI;
    
    currentThetaRadians = thetaRadians;
    
    oppIndicator.innerHTML = `Opposite: ${opp}`;
    adjIndicator.innerHTML = `Adjacent: ${adj}`;
    hypIndicator.innerHTML = `Hypotenuse: ${hyp}`;
    
    thetaIndicator.innerHTML = strThetaChar+" "+thetaDegrees.toFixed(2)+"º";
    
    
    passMotionData(opp, adj, hyp, thetaDegrees);  
}

function passMotionData(opp, adj, hyp, thetaDegrees){
    
    velocity_initial = hyp;
    angle = thetaDegrees.toFixed(2);
    time = null; 
    
    y_velocity_original = opp;
    y_velocity_final = 0;
    y_original = canvas.height;
    y_final = canvas.height;
    y_acceleration = document.getElementById("acceleration").value;
    max_height = null;
    
    x_velocity_original = adj;
    x_velocity_final = 0;
    x_original = 0;
    x_final = null;
    x_acceleration = 0;     
}

function drawVectorLine(){
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(origin.x, origin.y);
    ctx.lineTo(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
    ctx.stroke();
    
}

function drawAngleIcon(){
  var img = document.getElementById("angle");
  ctx.drawImage(img, origin.x+5, origin.y-14, 10, 10);
}

function clearScreen(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function updateMouse(event){
  var rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
     
  mousePosition.x = event.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
  mousePosition.y = event.clientY - rect.top;  //y position within the element.
    
  mouseInd.innerHTML = `X: ${mousePosition.x.toFixed(0)}  Y: ${mousePosition.y.toFixed(0)}`;
}


function checkCollisions(){
    
    let first, second;
    let p = 0;
    let stopInnerLoop = false;;
    
    if(Balls.length < 2) return;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < Balls.length; i++){   
        
        first = Balls[i];
        stopInnerLoop = false;
        p = 0;
        
        while(p < Balls.length && !stopInnerLoop){        
            second = Balls[p];
            
            if(i != p){
               if(distance(first, second) < first.radius + second.radius){
                 first.colliding = true;  
                 second.colliding = true;   
                 resolveCollision(first, second);
                 stopInnerLoop = true;  
               }
               else{
                 first.colliding = false;
                 second.colliding = false;   
               }  
                   
            } 
            
            p++;
        }
    }
    
    updateCollisionsCounter();
}

function distance(first, second){
    let diffX = Math.abs(first.position.x - second.position.x);
    let diffY = Math.abs(first.position.y - second.position.y);
    let distance = Math.sqrt(diffX*diffX + diffY*diffY);
      
    return distance;
}


function updateCollisionsCounter(){
    
    let collisionsElement = document.getElementById("collision");
    let counter = 0;
    
    collisionsElement.innerHTML = "No Collisions";
    
    for(let i = 0; i < Balls.length; i++){        
        if(Balls[i].colliding) counter++;
    }
    
    if(counter > 0){
        collisionsElement.innerHTML = "Balls Colliding x"+(counter);
    }
}

///funcions xungues de colisions
function rotate(velocity, angle){
    const rotatedVelocities = {
        x: velocity.x * Math.cos(angle) - velocity.y * Math.sin(angle),   
        y: velocity.x * Math.sin(angle) + velocity.y * Math.cos(angle)
    };
    
    return rotatedVelocities;
}


function resolveCollision(bubble, otherBubble){
    const xVelocityDiff = Math.abs(bubble.velocity.x - otherBubble.velocity.x);
    const yVelocityDiff = Math.abs(bubble.velocity.y - otherBubble.velocity.y);
    
    const xDist = otherBubble.velocity.x - bubble.velocity.x;
    const yDist = otherBubble.velocity.y - bubble.velocity.y;
    
    //prevent accidental overlap of bubbles
    if(xVelocityDiff * xDist + yVelocityDiff * yDist >= 0){
        
        
        //grab angle between the two colliding bubbles
        const angle = -Math.atan2(otherBubble.velocity.y - bubble.velocity.y, otherBubble.velocity.x - bubble.velocity.x);
        
        //store mass in var for better readability in collision equation
        const m1 = bubble.mass;
        const m2 = otherBubble.mass;
        
        //velocity before equation
        const u1 = rotate(bubble.velocity, angle);
        const u2 = rotate(otherBubble.velocity, angle);
        
        //velocity after 1 dimension collision equation
        const v1 = {x: u1.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u2.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2), y: u1.y };
        const v2 = {x: u2.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u1.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2), y: u2.y };
        
        //final velocity after rotating axis back to original location
        const vFinal1 = rotate(v1, -angle);
        const vFinal2 = rotate(v2, -angle);
        
        //swap bubbles velocities for realistic bounce effect
        bubble.velocity.x = vFinal1.x;
        bubble.velocity.y = vFinal1.y;
        
        otherBubble.velocity.x = vFinal2.x;
        otherBubble.velocity.y = vFinal2.y;
    }
}
////

function getFPS(){
    
    let delta;
    
    if(!lastCallTime){
        lastCallTime = Date.now();
        fps = 0;
        return;
    }
    
    delta = (Date.now() - lastCallTime) / 1000;
    lastCallTime = Date.now();
    fps = Math.floor(1/delta);
}
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
    user-select: none; /* Standard */
}


canvas {

    height: 500px;
    width: 1700px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

#infoarea {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around:
}

.subcontainer{
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px gray;
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Projectile Motion</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <h3 id="fpsIndicator">FPS: 0</h3>
        
        <h3 id="mouse">X:0  Y:0</h3>
              
        <canvas id="area" height=500 width=1700></canvas>
        
        <p id="collision">collision indicator</p>
        <p id="ballCount">NºBalls: 0</p>
        
        <br>
        <br>
               
        <div id="infoarea">
           
            <!-- triangle-->
            <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 220px; padding: 3px;">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;">TRIANGLE</h2>

                <h3 id="hypotenuse">hypotenuse: 0</h3>

                <h3 id="adj">adjacent: 0</h3>
                <h3 id="opp">opposite: 0</h3>
                <h3 id="theta">&theta;: 0.00º</h3>
                <h3 id="currentRads"></h3>
            </div>
            
            <!-- motion input -->
            <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 220px; padding: 3px;">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;">MOTION INPUT</h2>

                
                <div>
                    <p>Launch Velocity (m/s)</p>
                    <input type="number" id="velocity">
                </div>
                
                <div>
                    <p>Launch Angle (degrees)</p>
                    <input type="number" id="launchAngle">
                </div>
                
                <div>
                    <p>Vertical Acceleration (gravity)</p>
                    <select name="" id="acceleration">
                        <option value="-3.7">Mercury (3.7 m/s)</option>
                        <option value="-8.87">Venus (8.87 m/s)</option>
                        <option selected value="-9.807">Earth (9.807 m/s)</option>
                        <option value="-3.711">Mars (3.711 m/s)</option>
                        <option value="-24.79">Jupiter (24.79 m/s)</option>
                        <option value="-10.44">Saturn (10.44 m/s)</option>
                        <option value="-8.87">Uranus (8.87 m/s)</option>
                        <option value="-11.15">Neptune (11.15 m/s)</option>
                        <option value="-0.62">Pluto (0.62 m/s)</option>
                        <option value="-5000">STRONK GRAVITY (5000m/s)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            
            <!-- motion data -->
            <div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px;">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;">
                    PREDICTED MOTION DATA
                    <h4 style="text-align: center;">(with 0 collisions assumed)</h4>    
                </h2>
                

                <div id="container">
                  
                   <!-- fields -->
                   <div class="subcontainer">
                        <div>
                            <p>Vertical Velocity (m/s)</p>
                            <input type="number" id="Yvel">
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <p>Horizontal Velocity (m/s)</p>
                            <input type="number" id="Xvel">
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <p>Flight Time (seconds)</p>
                            <input type="number" id="time">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- fields 2 -->
                    <div class="subcontainer">
                        <div>
                            <p>Max Height achieved (m)</p>
                            <input type="number" id="mHeight">
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <p>X displacement (aprox.range)</p>
                            <input type="number" id="Xdisplacement">
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <p>Y Acceleration (gravity)</p>
                            <input type="number" id="yAcceleration">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                </div>    
                
            </div>
            
            <!-- manual input-->
            <div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px;">
               
                <h2 style="text-align: center;">MANUAL INPUT</h2>
                
                <div id="container">
                  
                   <!-- fields -->
                   <div class="subcontainer">
                       
                        <div>
                            <p>Launch Angle (degrees)</p>
                            <input type="number" id="mAngle">
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <p>Launch Velocity (m/s)</p>
                            <input type="number" id="mVelocity">
                        </div>

                       <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; margin-top: 3px;">
                            <button id="launchManual">
                                Launch!
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
            </div>
            
        </div>    
        
        
        <!-- THESE TWO IMAGES ARE SUPPOSED TO BE THE THETA SYMBOL FOR THE ANGLE, 
             AND THE ARROW TIP, FOR THE VECTOR, NOW THEY'RE EMPTY FOR OBVIOUS REASONS -->
        
        <img src="" id="angle" alt="" style="display: none;">
        <img src="" id="tip" alt="" style="display: none;">
    </body>
    
    <footer>
        <script src="ball.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="motion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </footer>
    
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, ggorlen, thx for suggesting this. Okey, it is done now.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Code Review! This is an interesting project and hopefully the information below is helpful. By the way, some of the statements and questions in the post (e.g. "*I can't get it to draw correctly. Sometimes it can't detect collisions.*" and "*How should I approach the arrow tip thing?*") could be perceived as making the post not [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site but the suggestions below pertain to the existing code.

There are fourteen variables declared with `const` though that does not mean that they are immutable - it just means they cannot be re-assigned. Properties of objects declared with `const` can be updated unless `Object.freeze()` is called on the object when it is assigned.  It is recommended that `const` be the default keyword used and then when re-assignment is deemed necessary switch to using `let`. There are very few reasons to use `var`.

Typically code in C-based languages
follows a convention where constants are named in ALL_CAPS. This code has `CANVAS_CLICKED` but that is not a constant. For the sake of readability use a consistent convention like `camelCase` or `snake_case` for that variable like the other variables. Additionally, Uppercase names are often reserved for classes, so while `Ball` is a class, the array `Balls` should be `balls`.

---

There are multiple functions that call `document.getElementById()` to fetch DOM elements. While it may not be a large issue with todays browsers, it is wise to cache those references to the DOM elements in variables because each lookup can be expensive.

[image: bridge toll]

> *”...DOM access is actually pretty costly - I think of it like if I have a bridge - like two pieces of land with a toll bridge,  and the JavaScript engine is on one side, and the DOM is on the other, and every time I want to access the DOM from the JavaScript engine, I have to pay that toll”*
>     - John Hrvatin, Microsoft, MIX09, in [this talk *Building High Performance Web Applications and Sites*](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX09/T53F) at 29:38, also cited in the [O'Reilly *Javascript* book by Nicholas C Zakas Pg 36](https://books.google.com/books?id=ED6ph4WEIoQC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=John+Hrvatin+%22DOM%22&source=bl&ots=2Wrd5G2ceJ&sig=pjK9cf9LGjlqw1Z6Hm6w8YrWOio&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcmZ7U_eDeAhVMGDQIHSfUAdoQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=John%20Hrvatin%20%22DOM%22&f=false), as well as mentioned in [this post](https://www.learnsteps.com/javascript-increase-performance-by-handling-dom-with-care/)

---

The click handler on the launcher button, i.e.

> ```
> manualLauncherBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
>   performManuaLaunch(); 
> });
> ```

could be simplified to:

```
manualLauncherBtn.addEventListener('click', performManuaLaunch)
```

---

The loops could be update to use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops in some places - e.g. instead of this loop in `updateBalls()`:

> ```
> for(let i = Balls.length-1 ; i >= 0; i--){       
>     Balls[i].draw();
>     Balls[i].move();
> }
> ```

It could be simplified to:

```
for(const ball of Balls){       
    ball.draw();
    ball.move();
}
```

Though bear in mind that performance would suffer. If you did want to keep the `for` loop, the post-loop operation could be combined with the *while* expression:

```
for(let i = Balls.length ; i--; /* intentionally blank */){
```

And this loop in `updateCollisionsCounter()` could be simplified from:

> ```
> for(let i = 0; i < Balls.length; i++){        
>     if(Balls[i].colliding) counter++;
> }
> ```

to:

```
const counter = Balls.filter(b => b.colliding).length;
```

Comment: According to the internet; `snake_case`, `kebab-case`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I have updated that section.